# Unknown Constructor error for extension controller

Tags: visualforce, controller, error, constructor

Hi im trying to use an extension controller for some kind of calculation in my vs page and getting error about the constructor: Unknown constructor...

any help with that?

**code**

```
 public with sharing class someExt
 {
        
    private final Object__c ob;

    public someExt (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.ob = (Object__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }
        
    public Integer intFunc() {
        Integer total =  [SELECT COUNT() FROM Object__c];
        Integer positive =  [SELECT COUNT() FROM Object__c WHERE Object__c.isPositive__c = true];  
        Integer p =positive/total;
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Always cut and paste the complete error message. The details can matter.

Answer (score 1):

For the constructor you have to work, your page must start with:

```
<apex:page standardController="Object__c" extensions="someExt" ...>
```

The runtime then knows what type of object to create the `StandardController` for and what class to create and pass the `StandardController` instance into.

See the [Building a Controller Exension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm) documentation for more information.